# Webpack for angular project - bundling angular dependencies without import/export

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I have a "huge" angular project, with lot directories with .less, .js, .html, .jpg etc. files:

I do not want to set the entry points and import/export statements in all of these files because it is impossible, I just want to include them to bundle 'dynamically' and run so I created a loader.js file which loads .js files:

```
function requireAll(r) { r.keys().forEach(r); }
requireAll(require.context('./src/', true, /\.js$/));
```

But now I have three problems:
1. This script loads only .js files (webpack says that I should use another loader for .html files)
2. I cannot load .html files separately in config because I will have a big amount of them.
3. This script loads .js files but there is a problem with dependencies. For example controller can be put earlier than module declaration what will cause an error.

To help you imagine my problem, I would like to include a library which contains a lot of .js and .html files. I do not know a structure of this library so I do not know what to import where but I want to have it in bundle.

How can I resolve my problem?

Regards